# Encryption using libsodium and need to generate public and private keys using crypto_box_keypair

Tags: javascript, cryptography, public-key, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I have been working with the libsodium library to implement Shamir secret sharing and trying to test the implementation done by dark crystal

https://gitlab.com/dark-crystal-javascript/key-backup-crypto/-/blob/master/example.js

Implementation is something like this

```
function encryptionKeypair () {
    const keypair = {
      publicKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES),
      secretKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES)
    }
    sodium.crypto_box_keypair(keypair.publicKey, keypair.secretKey)
    return keypair
  },

 function oneWayBox (message, publicKey) {
    console.log('in one way box');
    const curvePublicKey = sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES)
    // console.log('curvePublicKey', curvePublicKey.toString('hex'));
    console.log('curvePublicKey', curvePublicKey.length);
    console.log('publicKey', publicKey.length);
    
    sodium.crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519(curvePublicKey, publicKey)

    // console.log('curvePublicKey', curvePublicKey.toString('hex'));


    console.log('in one way box');
    console.log('\n');

    const ephemeral = this.encryptionKeypair()
    const nonce = this.randomBytes(sodium.crypto_box_NONCEBYTES)
    const cipherText = sodium.sodium_malloc(message.length + sodium.crypto_box_MACBYTES)
  
    sodium.crypto_box_easy(cipherText, message, nonce, curvePublicKey, ephemeral.secretKey)
    zero(ephemeral.secretKey)
    zero(message)
    return Buffer.concat([nonce, ephemeral.publicKey, cipherText])
  },
```

below is Secret-sharing-generation.js

```
const secrets = require('secret-sharing')
const s = require('.')

const secret = 'My secret key'
const label = ''

console.log('Secret to share:', secret.toString('hex'))

console.log(`Packing with label: '${label}'`)
const packedSecret = s.packLabel(secret, label)
console.log(`Packed secret: ${packedSecret.toString('hex')}`)
console.log(`Length of packed secret is ${packedSecret.length} bytes.`)
const signingKeypair = s.keypair()
const encryptionKeypair = s.signingKeypairToEncryptionKeypair(signingKeypair)

const custodians = []
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  custodians.push(s.encryptionKeypair())
}


console.log('custodians', custodians);

console.log('Creating 5 shares, 3 needed to recover')
secrets.share(packedSecret, 5, 3).then((shards) => {
  console.log('Shards:')
  console.log(shards.map(s => s.toString('hex')))
  console.log('Signed shards:')
  const signedShards = s.signShards(shards, signingKeypair)
  console.log(signedShards.map(s => s.toString('hex')))

  const boxedShards = signedShards.map((shard, i) => {
    return s.oneWayBox(shard, custodians[i].publicKey)
  })

  console.log('Boxed shards:')
  console.log(boxedShards.map(s => s.toString('hex')))
  console.log(`Length of boxed shards are ${boxedShards[0].length} bytes.`)
  secrets.combine(shards.slice(2)).then((result) => {
    console.log('Result of recombining 3 shares:', result.toString())
  })
})
```

Now the problem is when I am using `encryptionKeypair` function to generate key pair for and then after that when I am trying to generate to do `crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_curve25519` using the key pair generated in this `encryptionKeypair` function I am getting

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOMEM, Cannot allocate memory`

I have checked my swap space it is completely free

```
           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3138          83        2896           0         158        2908
Swap:          5119           0        5119
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you want to convert a key pair created with `encryptionKeypair()` with [`crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_curve25519()`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/advanced/ed25519-curve25519#usage) or [`crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519()`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/advanced/ed25519-curve25519#usage).

The latter two methods convert a secret or public Ed25519 key (used in the context of signing) to a secret or public X25519 key (used in the context of key exchange).

`encryptionKeypair()` applies [`crypto_box_keypair()`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption#key-pair-generation) and thus *already* creates an X25519 key pair, so conversion is not necessary (and not possible).

A working use of the conversion methods would be, e.g. using [`crypto_sign_keypair()`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures#key-pair-generation), which generates an Ed25519 key pair:

```
var sodium = require('sodium-native');
...
var ed25519KeyPair = signingKeypair() // Create an Ed25519 keypair
var x25519KeyPair = {
    publicKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES),
    secretKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES)
}
sodium.crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519(x25519KeyPair.publicKey, ed25519KeyPair.publicKey) // Convert the public Ed25519 into a public X25519 key
sodium.crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_curve25519(x25519KeyPair.secretKey, ed25519KeyPair.secretKey) // Convert the secret Ed25519 into a secret X25519 key
console.log(x25519KeyPair.publicKey)
console.log(x25519KeyPair.secretKey)

function signingKeypair () {
    const keypair = {
        publicKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES),
        secretKey: sodium.sodium_malloc(sodium.crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES)
    }
    sodium.crypto_sign_keypair(keypair.publicKey, keypair.secretKey)
    return keypair
}
```

Also, I can't reproduce the posted error message. When using `encryptionKeypair()` instead of `signingKeypair()`, I get the following error message *Error: public key conversion failed*.

**Edit:**

In the 2nd code snippet, the `custodians`' key pairs are created with `s.encryptionKeypair()`, which produces X25519 key pairs. In the later called `s.oneWayBox()` it is then tried to convert the public keys with `crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519()`, which must fail as described above.

Presumably this is a bug! A possible fix is to generate the `custodians`' key pairs with `s.keypair()` (or `signingKeypair()`), which creates Ed25519 key pairs. The public keys can then be successfully converted to X25519 keys in `s.oneWayBox()`. With this change, `oneWayBox()` runs without any errors on my machine.

This change to Ed25519 key pairs is also consistent with the description of [`encryptionKeypair()`](https://gitlab.com/dark-crystal-javascript/key-backup-crypto/-/blob/master/README.md#encryptionkeypair), which states that this method is only used when generating ephemeral keys, e.g. in `oneWayBox()`. In all other cases it is internally derived from Ed25519 keys.